# C# DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Hide/Gray-Out

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a `DataGridView` with several columns and several rows of data. One of the columns is a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` and (based on the other data in the row) I would like the option to "hide" the checkbox in some rows. I know how to make it read only but I would prefer it to not show up at all or at least display differently (grayed out) than the other checkboxes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some workaround: make it read-only and change back color to gray.
For one specific cell:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Style.BackColor =  Color.LightGray;
dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
```

Or, better but more "complicated" solution:
suppose you have 2 columns: first with number, second with checkbox, that should not be visible when number > 2. You can handle `CellPainting` event, paint only borders (and eg. background) and break painting of rest. Add event `CellPainting` for DataGridView (optionally test for DBNull value to avoid exception when adding new data in empty row):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    //check only for cells of second column, except header
    if ((e.ColumnIndex == 1) && (e.RowIndex > -1))
    {
        //make sure not a null value
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value != DBNull.Value)
        {
            //put condition when not to paint checkbox
            if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) > 2)
            {
                e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Border | DataGridViewPaintParts.Background);  //put what to draw
                e.Handled = true;   //skip rest of painting event
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should work, however if you change value manually in first column, where you check condition, you must refresh the second cell, so add another event like `CellValueChanged`:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        dataGridView1.InvalidateCell(1, e.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcell.aspx

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.Visible = false;
```

**Edit:** Oh, wait, it's read only. Derp.

In which case, try replacing the cell with an empty DataGridViewTextBoxCell.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Customize the Appearance of Cells in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hta8z9sz.aspx), you could catch the CellPainting event and not draw the cell if its in read only mode.  For example:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   dataGridView1.CellPainting += new 
      DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellPainting);
}

private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender,
   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
   // Change 2 to be your checkbox column #
   if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].Index == e.ColumnIndex && e.RowIndex >= 0)
   {
      // If its read only, dont draw it
      if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ReadOnly)
      {
         // You can change e.CellStyle.BackColor to Color.Gray for example
         using (Brush backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor))
         {
            // Erase the cell.
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);
            e.Handled = true;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The only caveat is that you need to call `dataGridView1.Invalidate();` when you change the `ReadOnly` property of one of the `DataGridViewCheckBox` cell's.