# How to hide a particular checkbox cell in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` that has some textboxtype columns and one checkboxtype column. CheckBoxColumn bind with a bool type property.

I want that if checkbox is checked it see in the grid else not as shown in figure.

[image]

I have added some code in databinding complete but it is giving compile time error `"Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Visible' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"`

```
private void dgvleftEdit_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{   
    var reportLogoList = cWShowInvoicePaymentDetailsBindingSource.List as IList<CWShowInvoicePaymentDetails>;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvleftEdit.Rows)
    {
        var objReport = row.DataBoundItem as CWShowInvoicePaymentDetails;
        var findItem = from f in reportLogoList
                       //where f.fReportID == objReport.fKey
                       select f;
        if (objReport.IsImage == false)
        {
            this.dgvleftEdit.Rows[row.Index].Cells[7].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.dgvleftEdit.Rows[row.Index].Cells[7].Visible = true;
        }
    } 
}
```

Is it possible to hide a particular cell in datagridview?

Comment: you want to hide `false` checkbox cells so how can you check them? Or you just need to show the checkbox cells without interaction?

Comment: it is coming from database.if IsImage is true in DB it gets checked in Datagribview.

Comment: I have also tried "this.dgvleftEdit["IsImage", row.Index] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();" but in cell it is showing true or false as a text.

Comment: are you using databinding to fill DB Data in dataGridView?

Comment: I am using binding source to fill DB DataGridView

Comment: I think you need to change that binding source structure. You should use bool?(Nullable boolean type) in that column so that you can set true value if exist and for false you can pass null value form database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide some datagridview checkbox cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124033/hide-some-datagridview-checkbox-cell)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want, if not leave some comment for why:

```
//CellPainting event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) {
   if (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex > -1 && dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn){
     if (e.Value == null || !(bool)e.Value) {
         e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, false);
         e.Handled = true;
     }
   }
}
//CellBeginEdit event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e){
   if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn){
            object cellValue = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
            e.Cancel = cellValue == null || !(bool)cellValue;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `DataGridVIewCheckBoxColumn` to `DataGridViewImageColumn`

Then in handler of `datagridview.CellFormatting`:

```
private void datagridview_CellFormatting(object sender,
                                          dataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewImageColumn)
    {
        if (e.Value != null && (bool)e.Value == true)
        {
            e.Value = My.Resources.yourCheckedImage;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Value = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then cell updating can handle with `MouseDown` handler  or some other handler of `Click`, `Enter` ..etc.

```
private void datagridview_MouseDown(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo click = dgv.HitTest(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
    //If your have predefined columns, then maybe better compare by Column.name
    if(click.RowIndex >= 0 && dgv.Columns(click.ColumnIndex) is DataGridViewImageColumn)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cellTmp = dgv.Row(click.RowIndex).Cells(click.ColumnIndex);
        if (cellTmp.Value == null)
        {
            cellTmp.Value = My.Resources.yourCheckedImage;
        }
        else
        {
            cellTmp.Value = null;
        }
    }
}
```