# Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Visible' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Tags: c#, datagridview, indexing

I have a datagridview consist of of 5 row something like this:

```
      int number = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
      dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = result;          
      dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[1].Value = newAddress;   
      dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[2].Value = (string)((Hashtable)ht[1])["value"];  
      dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[3].Value = (string)((Hashtable)ht[2])["value"];   
      dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[4].Value = (string)((Hashtable)ht[3])["value"];
      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
         {
             if (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "")
             {
                row.Cells[5].Visible = false; //error
             }
         }
```

Cell 5 is save button. Now I want to check if the cell number 4 is empty, then set the visibility for cell 5 false(hide button). However, I get this error at the commented line.

```
Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Visible' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

I've checked the datagridview1 and column readonly properties, it is all set to false. But I still face this error.

Can anyone please advice?

Comment: Error message isn't clear?

Comment: @SonerGönül The error message stated as above. Not sure why it stated read only. I have checked all the properties readonly set to false.

Comment: You need to hide specified cell or column?

Comment: @Lev yup,,I need to hide specified cell.

Comment: Try this answer. it seems similar to your request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124033/hide-some-datagridview-checkbox-cell

Comment: And this one: http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.co.il/2010/02/hide-specific-cell-values-in.html